# C - argv[] passed in * as parameter, returns 1 when printed

Tags: c

I'm trying to see if * is passed in as a parameter in argv, but I'm not sure how to begin testing for it. When I did a

```
printf("%s\n", argv[1]);
```

The code prints out 1. I tested and ran

```
./a.out \*
```

To escape the input, which did work and printed "*", but I want t be able to pass in * without escaping from the user end and be able to see that * is passed. I can't just test for

```
if (strcmp(argv[1], "1") == 0)
```

Because that'd be testing if I passed in 1 like

```
./a.out 1
```

How should I do this??

Comment: When you type "./a.out *" the shell interprets the star, expands it with the names of files in the current directory, and passes those to your program as argv[]. Unless you escape the *, your program will never see it.

Comment: It does not seem to be possible without escaping from the user end. Simply because you are not getting * in your program, but something that shell subsitutes for it. In your case "1". It can be anything at all

Comment: `argv[1] == "1"` does **not** compare strings in C. You're comparing pointers that are never being equal.

Answer (score 3):

This is nothing to do with c. Its your shell processing its line before running your program. You don't specify your os, but you will need to escape the arguments whatever

Comment: That's a real bummer then. I guess I'll just have to escape on user end.

Answer (score 3):

The shell is responsible for command line preprocessing before it runs a program. `*` is knowns as a wildcard. It is not the only wildcard, there are also `?`, `[`, `{` and substitutons of `$`. You can escape preprocessing wildcards by prefixing them with `\` or enclosing parameters in quotations `'`

```
./a.out '*'
```

> I can't just test for

```
if (argv[1] == "1")
```

> Because that'd be testing if I passed in 1 like

```
./a.out 1
```

You can not test it either. `argv[1] == "1"` does not compare strings, it compares pointers and the comparison always is false.